# why a mobile is not able to read nfc (mifare) tag

Tags: android, nfc

I have developed an app for reading and writing to NFC tags. The app is working fine on Sony xperia c3 but not able to read a tag in a low-end device(iball andi enigma). I am not getting why this is happening.
The mobile on which i have installed the app has NFC support. I have already enable the settings like reading and writing in the mobile. The mobile is able to recognize the NFC card but showing that the tag is empty even if it has a record containing a string value. Anybody have any idea about this issue? Please help...

Comment: MifareClassic support is optional. Your low-end device may simply not have support for it.

Comment: I think this might be the issue...

Answer (score -1):

Check your mobile has nfc capabilities:

1. On your Android device, tap on Settings.
2. Under Wireless & Networks, tap More.
3. Scroll down and you should see the NFC and Android Beam options.

Is it there?

If your device has NFC, the chip and Android Beam need to be activated so that you can use NFC:

1. Go to Settings > Wireless & Networks > More.
2. Tap on the NFC switch to activate it. The Android Beam function will
   also automatically turn on.
3. If Android Beam does not automatically turn on, just tap it and
   select Yes to turn it on.

Smartphones’ NFC capabilities operate in tandem with Android Beam. If Android Beam is disabled, it may limit NFC’s sharing capacity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, take a look at this complete article about NFC (maybe you've already read it):  [link](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-use-nfc-android-2-164644/)

Comment: Yes it is a NFC supported device. I have already done as you have told me to do. The problem still persists.